# are "indicate" and signify used interchangeably?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

are "indicate" and signify used interchangeably?

for example I know that it is correct to say "this decision **signified** a fundamental change in their priorities" but is it correct to use **indicated** instead of ***signified***.

another example here "dotted lines indicate the text's margins" also here  is it correct to use **signify** instead of ***indicate***.

Comment: A quick check of the first five results for "indicate signify synonym" returns five thesaurus pages, and all five say they are close synonyms. Do you need something more specific or nuanced than that?

Comment: If you compare the definitions of the two words you should be able to see which usages match. To do that, you need to understand the meaning in context of the word in question, then check if that meaning exists for both words, or not.

Comment: These words are synonyms in every usage I can think of off the top of my head. A better question might be "when are indicate and signify *not* interchangeable".

Comment: As a native English speaker I've never seen signify used with an indirect object, but have often seen one used with indicate.  "His decision indicated a fundamental change in their priorities [to the workforce]." doesn't work if you replace "indicated" with "signify".

Comment: Google translator uses this example "this decision signified a fundamental change in their priorities"!

Answer (score 0):

I am not a native speaker but for me,

**signify** could mean ***indicate*** and ***imply***

**indicate** means just ***indicate***.